# How can I strip namespaces out of an lxml tree?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces, prefix

Following on from [Removing child elements in XML using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210515/removing-child-elements-in-xml-using-python) ...

Thanks to @Tichodroma, I have this code:

If you can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/), try this:

```
 import lxml.etree

 tree = lxml.etree.parse("leg.xml")
 for dog in tree.xpath("//Leg1:Dog",
                       namespaces={"Leg1": "http://what.not"}):
     parent = dog.xpath("..")[0]
     parent.remove(dog)
     parent.text = None
 tree.write("leg.out.xml")
```

Now `leg.out.xml` looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Leg1:MOR xmlns:Leg1="http://what.not" oCount="7">
   <Leg1:Order>
     <Leg1:CTemp id="FO">
       <Leg1:Group bNum="001" cCount="4"/>
       <Leg1:Group bNum="002" cCount="4"/>
     </Leg1:CTemp>
     <Leg1:CTemp id="GO">
       <Leg1:Group bNum="001" cCount="4"/>
       <Leg1:Group bNum="002" cCount="4"/>
     </Leg1:CTemp>
   </Leg1:Order>
 </Leg1:MOR>
```

How do I modify my code to remove the `Leg1:` namespace prefix from all of the elements' tag names?

Comment: I had a look and couldn't get it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove namespace and prefix from xml in python using lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159221/remove-namespace-and-prefix-from-xml-in-python-using-lxml)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One possible way to remove namespace prefix from each element :

```
def strip_ns_prefix(tree):
    #iterate through only element nodes (skip comment node, text node, etc) :
    for element in tree.xpath('descendant-or-self::*'):
        #if element has prefix...
        if element.prefix:
            #replace element name with its local name
            element.tag = etree.QName(element).localname
    return tree
```

Another version which has namespace checking in the xpath instead of using `if` statement :

```
def strip_ns_prefix(tree):
    #xpath query for selecting all element nodes in namespace
    query = "descendant-or-self::*[namespace-uri()!='']"
    #for each element returned by the above xpath query...
    for element in tree.xpath(query):
        #replace element name with its local name
        element.tag = etree.QName(element).localname
    return tree
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. It also fits perfectly into my methods.

Comment: You may also need to call `etree.cleanup_namespaces(tree)` - otherwise `etree.tostring(tree)` will still show namespaces.

Comment: The second method is more robust (to default namespaces)